# git: checkout vs merge vs ?? for resolving conflicts in favor of ours selectively

Tags: git, merge

There seem to be a thousand variations on this theme, and many have been asked, but I can't seem to find the appropriate solution for me.

I have two lines of development, one on "master" done by me (ours) and one on a branch, "their_new_stuff".  Both have changed a significant number of files, touching many of the files in the same place and creating conflicts.

Now I need to merge their work into our work, and deal with conflicts in the following way:  For 99% of those conflicts, I can simply accept "ours". However, I also need all changes that they made that don't conflict and, in a few key conflicts, I need to accept theirs or merge by hand.  Knowing which files need manual merging or "theirs" in the merge requires manual inspection.

I have tried the following:

Try 1:

```
git merge their_new_stuff
# for each file with conflicts:
    # if requires manual merge:
        # do manual merge
    # else:
        git checkout --ours all/files/not/merged/by/hand.cc
```

At first I thought this was what I wanted, but this doesn't work because checkout with "ours" is full-file checkout, and doesn't only checkout/resolve the parts that are conflicting.  So I lose non-conflicting changes of theirs that I want.

Try 2:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xours their_new_stuff
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't allow single file merges.  I need to know where there are conflicts, and would like to see the file version with conflict markers to help me do the manual merges, so ideally I would do something after a failed merge.

Try 3: Then I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
git merge their_new_stuff
# for each file with conflict:
    # if file needs manual merge:
        cp file file2
git merge --abort
git merge -s recursive -Xours their_new_stuff
# for each file with manual merge:
    cp file2 file
    # merge by hand
```

I think this should work, but it feels very klugy.  Is there a "right" way to do this?  Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
git merge their_new_stuff
# for each file with conflict
    # if needs manual merge
        # do manual merge
    # else
        # is there any command that does something like?:
        git remerge -s recursive -Xours file
```

Effectively I want to do the merge, getting conflict markers.  Inspect for manual merges, and if a manual merge is not needed, redo the merge on just that file using "-Xours".  Is this possible?

Comment: Git does have `git-merge-file`, which you can use on a per-file basis. Note that in order *to* use it you must extract (typically, from the three stages in the index) the base (stage 1), local (`--ours`), and other (`--theirs`) files into ordinary file-system files. Note that `merge-file` *does* take `--ours` and `--theirs` which have the `-X` style meaning.

Comment: @torek Thanks, didn't know about that.  This is interesting -- I guess I could do a ``merge`` to see conflicts, then abort, then use ``merge-file --ours`` on the "keep ours" files and ``merge-file`` without ``--ours`` to get the conflict markers on the "manual merge" files.  If something better doesn't come up soon, feel free to make this an answer and I'd accept.

Comment: You don't even need (nor probably want) to abort the merge: you want to extract the three index versions of the file into temporaries, and those remain *in* the index only while the file remains unresolved.  (See also: `git ls-files --stage`, `git ls-files --unmerged`.)

Answer (score 2):

Git is a *respository* based version control system, meaning that changes in state in a Git branch generally apply to *all* the files in that branch.  This is conceptually different to other VCS tools, such as SVN, where individual files can be manipulated and committed.  There is no concept in Git as a single file merge.  If you merge two branches, then *all* the files would need to be reconciled during the merge.

> Both have changed a significant number of files, touching many of the files in the same place and creating conflicts.

I believe this is the root cause of your problem.  Ideally, you and your partner should be working on different areas of the code base such that when you merge there are minimal conflicts.  Large numbers of merge conflicts imply, in my opinion, poor branching design and strategy.  Two software people working inside the same Java class may cause merge conflicts, two people working inside the very same method is even worse.  Try to see if you can separate your concerns in such a way as to minimize conflicts later.

That being said, with regard to your current problem I would just advise you to merge by hand.  If you are certain that you want either parent's version of the file, then use one of the following:

```
git checkout --theirs <path/to/file.ext>
git checkout --ours <path/to/file.ext>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I get that a merge is a repo-wide concept, but my impression (I'm a long-time mercurial user, but new to git) was that git had a lot of support for hunk-level merging.  I guess that is what I need to learn?  While your ideal situation would be nice, it just isn't the case on this project with 10s of developers.  The 99% of conflicts are really a changed constructor interface, and two people actually changed it in NEARLY the same way.

Comment: @EthanCoon In my experience, if you aren't smart enough to resolve an ugly merge conflict, then Git usually isn't either.  Yes, you could try to create scripts to automate this, but I am maximally paranoid when resolving merge conflicts and always do it by hand.  Maybe someone else will give you a different answer.

Comment: I'm smart enough to do it, I'm just lazy!  At a glance I can see that I want "ours", but only for that interface change.  Since checkout IS file-wise, not hunk-wise, that doesn't work.  If the file has only interface-change conflicts, then resolving all conflicts in favor of ours would work, but I don't seem to be smart enough to tell git to do this.